# How do I create a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

How do you create community wikis? I've seen some and I have an idea for one, but I don't know how to create one.

EDIT: The reason I am asking is because I've seen several questions, not only on this site, but others, that would be helpful if they were made into wikis. Example: I saw a question yesterday asking about free sound effects. It would be helpful if someone would create a community wiki with free sound effect sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create community wiki questions without the assistance of a moderator because ... well, that feature was abused. What did you have in mind, specifically? Can you edit your Q to elaborate?

Some context: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-to-kill-off-community-wiki-entries

You can still mark *answers* community wiki at will, but it is a one-way street.

Additional guidance at: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: How do you mark answers? I edited my question to elaborate.

Comment: if you believe a question should be community wiki, flag it for moderator attention and indicate why. As for marking answers, see http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask